# Laravel 5.3 Ajax - Retrieve data sent in the ajax request from the controller

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

#### index.html

```
<form id="my-form">
 <select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">Tom</option>
  <option value="2">Jerry</option>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" value="send data!">
</form>
```

#### Controller.php

```
public function getValue(Request $request)
{
 return User::find($request->input('select_id'));
}
```

#### ajax.js

```
$(function () {

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

var showUser = $('#show-user');

$('#my-form').on('submit', function () {

    var select_id = $('#my-select').val();

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "ajax",
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        data: {
            "select_id": select_id
        },
        error: function (data) {
            //something went wrong with the request
            alert("Error");
        },
        success: function (data) {
            inner = "";
            data.forEach(function (el, i, array) {
                inner += "<div>" + el.name + "</div>";
            });
            showUser.html(inner);
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

#### web.php

```
Route::post('ajax','Controller@getValue');
```

#### Update:

@Mahdi Youseftabar -> Thanks for it, according to the documentation I should use input() to get the request!

**Problem 1: Error: 500 (TokenMismatchException);**

**What I did?**

Add meta to :

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

I set the headers:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

    $.ajax({
    ...
        headers: {
            'X-Auth-Token' : token
        },
    ...
    });
```

### What I need to do?

- *Retrieve the id sent in the ajax request from the controller* [SOLVED]
- *Validate the token by the ajax request** Error 505 (Problem 1)* [SOLVED]
- *Return from the controller is Empty* [SOLVED]
- *Output the Users into the `<div class="showUser"></div>`* [SOLVED]

**Github Documentation of my project:** 
(Many to many relationships - Laravel 5.3, Ajax)
https://github.com/39ro/StudentSchoolProject

Comment: So, what is the problem? Is there something not working? Do you get an error somewhere?

Comment: I think in the ajax request you have add the value like this: `data: { userid: userid }`

Comment: Have you tried my method/?

Comment: Yes, but I am still getting 500 error. I update the ajax.js and index.html code to explain what I am currently looking to achieve!

Comment: Have you tried to do a check in your VerifyCsrfToken.php file? I suggested a similar attempt in answers as illustrated here: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-tokenmismatchexception-with-ajax-post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is in route :

```
Route:post('ajax','Controller@getValue');
```

you use post method in your jQuery but in route you define that route method 'get' ...

in this case when you request with ajax, laravel respond you a empty response

another issue is in getting your user_id from request, you should use this in your controller:

```
return User::find($request->input('user_id');
```

Comment: It was a mistake to write here the type of ajax call was already made with a "post"! Thanks for the suggestion, but the value_select is still null!

Comment: another issue i found ... check it

Answer (score 0):

Two things check

In js

```
data: {"userid" : userid}
method: "POST",
```

in controller

```
$value_select =  User::where($request->userid)->first();
return $value_select;
```

Now check the response and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

If you don't get an error, and the result is null then you probably missing something.

> Remember that find() function you use in your controller is searching for primary key only.

And its an ajax request so you wont see it in the browser. To see the return value you should look in the

> Developer tools > Network > and then find the request to see the
>   preview and response

Answer (score 0):

**Add relationship to Controller.php**

My problem was the relationship with the other two table. 
I update my main Question with the link to my GitHub Project, where I applied all your suggestions! Thanks everyone, I solved it!

For the token I solved adding what I showed in Ajax.js.

And to retrieve the data from the relationship I just make it:

```
public function getValue(Request $request)
{
return User::find($request->input('select_id'))->relationship_table;
}
```